# How do I split orders between Magento Multi Stores?

Tags: magento, store, magento-1.7

We have a magneto store and we sell decorations that are season based. So we need to have Magento possibly split into multi stores each housing the different seasons. But I need it to ONLY allow orders from 1 season to go through the system at a time not to have the customer able to mix their products up and then complete that order.

Does anyone know if it is possible to have settings changed to lock products/carts to a single store with in a multi store site?

Thanks,

Simon.

Comment: Why not just disable the other stores when they aren't in use? :)

Comment: Thanks for the input Andrew but we sell our products all year round, just that we send them out when we are leading up to the beginning season.